# GLSL uv lookup and precision with FBO / RenderTarget in Three.js

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader, gpgpu

My application is coded in Javascript + Three.js / WebGL + GLSL. I have 200 curves, each one made of 85 points. To animate the curves I add a new point and remove the last. 
So I made a `positions` shader that stores the new positions onto a texture (1) and the `lines` shader that writes the positions for all curves on another texture (2).
**The goal is to use textures as arrays: I know the first and last index of a line, so I need to convert those indices to `uv` coordinates.**

I use [FBOHelper](https://github.com/spite/THREE.FBOHelper) to debug FBOs.

1) This 1D texture contains the new points for each curve (200 in total): `positionTexture`

[image]

2) And these are the 200 curves, with all their points, one after the other: `linesTexture`

[image]

The black parts are the BUG here. Those texels shouldn't be black.
How does it work: at each frame the shader looks up the new point for each line in the `positionTexture` and updates the `linesTextures` accordingly, with a `for` loop like this:

```
#define LINES_COUNT = 200
#define LINE_POINTS = 85 // with 100 it works!!!

// Then in main()

vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;

for (float i = 0.0; i < LINES_COUNT; i += 1.0) {
    float startIdx = i * LINE_POINTS; // line start index
    float endIdx = beginIdx + LINE_POINTS - 1.0; // line end index
    vec2 lastCell = getUVfromIndex(endIdx); // last uv coordinate reserved for current line

if (match(lastCell, uv)) {
      pos = texture2D( positionTexture, vec2((i / LINES_COUNT) + minFloat, 0.0)).xyz;
    } else if (index >= startIdx && index < endIdx) {
      pos = texture2D( lineTexture, getNextUV(uv) ).xyz;
    }
  }
```

This works, but it's slightly buggy when I have many lines (150+): likely a precision problem. I'm not sure if the functions I wrote to look up the textures are right. I wrote functions like `getNextUV(uv)` to get the value from the next index (converted to uv coordinates) and copy to the previous. Or `match(xy, uv)` to know if the current fragment is the texel I want.

I though I could simply use the classic formula:

```
index = uv.y * width + uv.x
```

But it's more complicated than that. For example `match()`:

```
// Wether a point XY is within a UV coordinate
float size = 132.0; // width and height of texture
float unit = 1.0 / size;
float minFloat = unit / size;

bool match(vec2 point, vec2 uv) {
    vec2 p = point;

    float x = floor(p.x / unit) * unit;
    float y = floor(p.y / unit) * unit;

    return x <= uv.x && x + unit > uv.x && y <= uv.y && y + unit > uv.y;
}
```

Or `getUVfromIndex()`:

```
vec2 getUVfromIndex(float index) {
  float row = floor(index / size); // Example: 83.56 / 10 = 8
  float col = index - (row * size); // Example: 83.56 - (8 * 10) = 3.56
  col = col / size + minFloat; // u = 0.357
  row = row / size + minFloat; // v = 0.81

  return vec2(col, row);
}
```

Can someone explain what's the most efficient way to lookup values in a texture, by getting a `uv` coordinate from `index` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture coordinates go from the edge of pixels not the centers so your formula to compute a UV coordinates needs to be

```
 u = (xPixelCoord + .5) / widthOfTextureInPixels;
 v = (yPixelCoord + .5) / heightOfTextureInPixels;
```

So I'm guessing you want `getUVfromIndex` to be

```
uniform vec2 sizeOfTexture;   // allow texture to be any size
vec2 getUVfromIndex(float index) {
  float widthOfTexture = sizeOfTexture.x;
  float col = mod(index, widthOfTexture);
  float row = floor(index / widthOfTexture);

  return (vec2(col, row) + .5) / sizeOfTexture;
}
```

Or, [based on some other experience with math issues in shaders](https://github.com/greggman/vertexshaderart/issues/6) you might need to fudge index

```
uniform vec2 sizeOfTexture;   // allow texture to be any size
vec2 getUVfromIndex(float index) {
  float fudgedIndex = index + 0.1;
  float widthOfTexture = sizeOfTexture.x;
  float col = mod(fudgedIndex, widthOfTexture);
  float row = floor(fudgedIndex / widthOfTexture);

  return (vec2(col, row) + .5) / sizeOfTexture;
}
```

If you're in WebGL2 you can use `texelFetch` which takes integer pixel coordinates to get a value from a texture

Comment: The `mod(index % widthOfTexture);` should'nt  be `mod(index, widthOfTexture);` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it fixed the buggy cases immediately! I'll test more to see if the other lookup functions are ok. Do you think the `match()` function that i posted in the question makes sense?

Comment: It works because `unit` is `1 / sizeOfTexture.x`: so it checks if `uv.x` is between the beginning and the end of a texel, but it's awful I think. How would you test to "match" a given uv coordinate (coming from an index value) with the current uv? Assuming you use your `getUVfromIndex` function to get the uv coordinate

Comment: You confused x and uv. What we need to test is if the `uv` (the current fragment) is between the two values. It works. Maybe it's more clear the other way round: `uv.x >= x && uv.x < x + unit`. But it's the same. I was wondering if there is a better way, but it seems you don't find the approach wrong.

Comment: Nope. You're reading it wrong :) `uv.x >= x && uv.x < x + unit`. uv.x is more/equal x and less than x + unit

Comment: Like I mentioned, brain fart. for some reason my brain kept sign `+ unit` on the other side 